ESP32-S3(Espressif社 SoC） 内蔵コントローラ(DMA等）レジスタ マップは公開されていない？
EspressifのHPで以下の資料にはI/Oマップのような情報は載っていない。

ESP32-S3 Techinical Reference Manual
ESP32-S3 DataSheet

ESP32-S3 ボードをArduino IDE環境で動かしている。
WiFiの送信電力設定で、出力を抑え気味にしても消費電力が変わらない。
H/Wに正しく”送信電力設定”がなされているか、H/Wのレジスタ値を読んで確認したいが情報無し。
EDP-IDFのCoreやライブラリのコードを見ても、最深部がバイナリで提供されていて、ソースコードからレジスタのアドレスを特定できない。
何かしらの情報をお持ちの方、おられないでしょうか？

そのチップそのものでは無いかもしれませんが、こんな記事が参考になるかも。ESP32マウスPart.40　ESP32のアドレスマッピングを理解する, M5StickC非公式日本語リファレンス, M5StickCのIOについて調べてみた あと例えばDMAについては ESP32-S3 Technical Reference Manual の355ページから長い説明が記述されているようですが。

kunifさんご指摘の通り、Espressif社が公開している"technical reference manual"にそれらしい記述がありました（当方の確認が足らなかった。）。ただ、WiFiに関しての情報は、やはり載っていないみたい。

「載っていない」というより, どのように接続されてるか調べてみては？ 例えばラズパイBluetoothはシリアル通信経由。Wi-Fi通信モジュールとのやりとりがMMIOとは限らないのでは。あと省電力にはLow Power Mode User Guideが参考になるかも

仕様文書サイトにこんな概要記事 ESP32-S3 Wi-Fi Power-saving Mode があるようですね。その詳細が書かれているという oriri さんが紹介されているページは英語化がまだ行われていないようですが、中国語版 低功耗模式使用指南 があるようです。google翻訳などの機械翻訳は出来るようですので調べてみてはどうでしょう？

kunif様、 oriri様  コメント ありがとうございます。 当方も色々調べ絵ているので、いくつか情報を記述します。 oriri様の”接続”に関してですが、EPS32-S3 はWiFi関連のコントローラ（トランシーバー等も含む）を内蔵しています。SPI等で外部のWiFiハードウェアとつながっているわけではない（SoCのマニュアルには、内蔵していると書かれている。が、詳細不明）。”Low Power Mode ～”に関しては、多分 Light / Deep Sleepのことで、英文ドキュメントが存在しています。100[ μ秒]のLigth Sleepを試してみましたが、省電力効果は見られなかった。

kunif様ご指摘の、"ESP32-s3 Wi-Fi Power-saving Mode"ですが、Arduino Sketch環境では、デフォルト で Power Saving Enableになっています。また、当方の環境では、即応性が必要なので、DTIMを大きくすることができません。github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/v5.1/examples/wifi/power_save

省電力化で試してみたこと、その１  WiFiGenericClass::setTxPower() で、WiFi送信出力を2[dBm]に落とす。その２、CPUの動作クロックを240Mhz => 80MHzに落とす。その３，main loop内に100[μ秒[のLight Sleep( esp_light_sleep_start )を入れる。 その４、main loop内でwaiti( 8086のHALT命令のようなもの）する。

前記対策をしても、省電力効果はほとんどありませんでした。アプリケーションの概要  1[kHz]でアナログ信号をサンプリング。100[ms]枚にUDPで100[samples]のデータをWiFi 送信。

Lipoバッテリーでの実測動作時間 、XIAO ESP32S3 Sense + 110mHhバッテリー で 50分。M5Capsule(250[mHh)で、180分。なお、複数回実測しているが、動作時間はかなりばらつきます。
